# Upload image to client without sending to server [dropzone.js]

Tags: dropzone.js

How can I have the user upload an image, then without sending it to a server give me the base64 version of the image?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL But why do you need a b64 version of it ? If it's only to display it in the page, then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)